# Prevent Chrome from caching my Website

Tags: html, .htaccess, google-chrome, caching, web

I am hosting a website (Apache) and as I am making changes often in the contents, I would like to prevent browsers to cache it.

This is my `<head>` field in some of my HTML files (the ones that change often).

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <meta name="description" content="...">
  <meta name="keywords" content="...">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/sitestyle.css" media="screen" />


  <title> ... </title>

  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
</head>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as Chrome continues to cache the website. But also the weird thing that happens is that even when I clear the cache of the browser, it still appears as the old version of the website.

The files I changed and uploaded were the correct ones, and I know that because when I open the website from an incognito window, the changes appear normally!

I also tried including this piece of code in the `.htaccess` file, but that still didn't work and resulted in the same weird thing where from Incognito I can see the changes, but not from Chrome with a cleared cache.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

Anyone know why this happens?

Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: You can add random string/number to css and js URL parametrs, like: styles/sitestyle.css?v=12345 every refresh. But i guess it's not exactly answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to remind:

1. Keep in mind that when changing today a caching time (from let's say 1 month back to 1 minute), the effect can't be seen untill the old caching time is passed. (So next month there are no more 'old' rules for using caches and after that month: each minute is checked for freshness).
2. Not only your browser uses caches, also proxies does. So you just have to wait till the old chache times are gone by.
   The only option you have if you want your changes RIGHT-NOW, is (like already suggested), use different filenames. This is also explained in the notes on [Google Developers on caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) - bottom part.